# select the commonjs file when running under commonjs of a dependency when running nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am running node 14.

I have a package that has this in the package.json

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
```

There are no browser or module fields.

It is a typescript project that I compile to a `.cjs` output.

The problem is that when I start nodemon like this:

```sh
nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec ts-node ./src/index.ts
```

I get this error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/blah/dist/index.js

The module in question has `module`, 'main`and`browser`fields but its type is`module`.

It has `index.js` and `index.cjs` files but `index.js` file is being chosen.

everything is fine when I run the compiled output that which is a `.cjs` file.

Is there a way to let node know that I want everything to run under commonjs.

Comment: If my answer doesn't work for you then could you please proved an MVP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to have node do what you want. I had a similar where the main project was commonjs but one of the libraries was esm or a library it was using was esm. I don't remember the specific details but it was a royal pain.

The basic work around is to use `esm` to `import` the library giving you issue. It likely that once you do that you will end up with a second layer of issues.

```
// example
const esmImport = require('esm')(module)
const {CookieJar, fetch} = esmImport('node-fetch-cookies')
```

Dynamic import also resolved the issue for me.

```
async init() {
        const { CookieJar } = await import('node-fetch-cookies')
        this.cookieJar = new CookieJar()
        this.cookieJar.addCookie(`username=${this._user}`, this._url.toString())
        this.cookieJar.addCookie('hippa=yes', this._url.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I used single quotation for multi-value args like `--exec' to solve it.

```
nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec 'ts-node ./src/index.ts'
```